# "gateway to gateway link" in VoIP?

Tags: voip

I want to route some calls to my VoIP number a call center overseas. The call center is telling me that I need to do a "gateway to gateway link" in order to make this happen. I'm not exactly sure what that is and can't seem to find anything on the net about it. I'm new to VoIP and want to be able to have an intelligent conversation with the call center provider.

What is a "gateway to gateway link?" And will I suffer any degradation of voice quality by doing this?

Comment: Do you have your own VoIP gateway?

Comment: I'm signing up for VoIP service. I assume they have a gateway?

Comment: If you don't have a VoIP gateway, you can't do a gateway-to-gateway link with the provider's gateway. I think you need to edit your question with a better description of what you have and what you ate wanting to accomplish. Explain where the calls originate, what route you want them to take, and where you want them to end. You need to have some sort of control over the calls which you wish to route.

Comment: i just edit my answer

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dear you need to know that voice GW ***(VG)*** can't communicate other VG without Call agent involved in this communication and this call agent could be centralized and both VG have connectivity to it through WAN connection for example .

***if your business is small growing***

1. you can use  some sort of of small business call agent (i.e. Cisco call manager express CME) in both sides which can handle Voip calls over WAN and local,mobile and international calls through PSTN  and if you want to obtain small call center it has call center express as well but it is licensed feature.
2. you also can use open source call agent like Asterisk and register those GW on it
3. if you don't want to bay any equipment other that your IP phones you can join ISP which can run telephone service on it , which is called ***ITSP***, ITSP will handle all VOIP feature you need (i.e. dial peers , route patterns , conferences , auto attendance and so on) please check this link [VOIP INFO](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Sip+Trunking+Providers)

   - degradation may you found for solution 1 and 2 is the WAN connection quality and this issue is solved by using QOS cross the WAN connection.
   - degradation may you found for solution 3 is the cost where you will bay for each call you make

***NOTE***

1. the VG register on the call agent by certain registration protocols some of them is open source any one can make use of like H323 and other are proprietary like Cisco MGCP.
2. i don't aim to mention any product by its name it just for example.